# Clear selected items on click and prevent function from always executing

Tags: angular, types, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I'm trying to use mat-select-autocomplete but I am having some problems with its implementation.

**First** problem is that the function's (selectionChange) = "getSelectedOptions ($ event)" event is always running each time I click on mat-select-autocomplete. Is there a way to perform this function only when I select an option?

**Second** problem: is there a way to clear the selected items after clicking the submit button?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jbbwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-select-autocomplete class="grid-7-11"
    [placeholder]="'Options Selection'"
    [errorMsg]="errorMessage"
    [showErrorMsg]="showError"
    [options]="options"
    [display]="'display'"
    [value]="'value'"
    [multiple]='true'
    [labelCount]="2"
    [selectedOptions]="selectedOptions"
    (selectionChange)="getSelectedOptions($event)">
  </mat-select-autocomplete>
</div>

<button (click)="clear()">Submit and clear selects</button>
```

**.ts**

```
  selected: any[]=[];
  showError = false;
  errorMessage = '';


  getSelectedOptions(selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
    console.log(this.selected)
  }

  clear(){ 
    this.selected = [];
    console.log(this.selected)
  }
```

Can someone help me? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using native `select`'s [selectionChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event).
By looking at the documentation of `mat-autocomplete` you should be using [optionSelected](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to implement, but the event / function does not executed :(

Comment: ah, I see, you're using (this) [https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-select-autocomplete ] module. Well, that should be fixed by the library author. You already have autocomplete provided by angular, I would use it. If, however, you still want to use this package then you could filter the input with the code I posted in an update.